# Paperclip styles attribute doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, styles, imagemagick, paperclip

i can upload a photo BUT when i add the styles doesnt work.

```
has_attached_file :photo , :styles => { :thumb => "150x150>", :normal => "492x600>"}
```

when i remove the style it works.

```
has_attached_file :photo
```

i have read that the cocaine is the problem so i put:

```
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'cocaine', '0.3.2'
```

in the error says:

Building photos photo C:/Users/kosh/AppData/Local/Temp/cottage-style-copper-house-copenhagen-120130320-1680-yk1kyj.jpg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.

alsow i have read that rmagick doent need it any more.
any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on [documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#image-processor), ImageMagik must be installed, so as images can be processed.

You can download it for Windows [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows), and you must configure it in Paperclip providing the directory where generated images are placed:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"
```

in `config/environments/development.rb`.

**EDIT**

Since the use of `:styles` causes ruby to use ImageMagick, the only source of problem I can think about is misconfiguration of this plugin. It would be nice if you can check if ImageMagick is working standalone: [Windows usage](https://web.archive.org/web/20201107230602/http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/windows/)

Comment: The `command_path` isn't always `/usr/local/bin/`, running `which convert` will show the exact route.

Comment: Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/" is not this the problem because i have it and work fine when i remove the styles..

Comment: As @Zippie said, you must check if that's the path in your case. It works without styles, because ImageMagik isn't needed if you won't using styles.

Comment: @Joao, the really tricky part is that marios had some problem with his app a week ago and couldn't figure it out. I cloned his project and made it work but it didn't work with `styles`. I couldn't figure it out back then and can't figure why it still isn't working, cause my other projects work normally with `styles`. If you have some suggestions i would be really glad to know the source of this kind of problem. Why it wouldn't work with his project on my computer but it did with my other ones? Maybe some difference in ruby/rails versions? But that doesn't seem right

Comment: @Zippie, are you also using Windows? If it's working on your environment, and not working on marios', it may be some misconfiguration. In Windows, it may be necessary to export environment variables for ImageMagick, as is shows on the video marios posted.

Comment: @Joao, no i'm working in Ubuntu and i have imagemagick installed. The really confusing part is why his code on my computer won't work with paperclip styles but my other apps work with paperclip styles just fine.

Comment: @JoãoDaniel  btw i thing i have install the imagemagick because in the folder of the web side there is a folder called imagemagick.

Comment: Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"  how to i found the right path to use?

Comment: @Zippie he was right. i havent install the imagemagick. now that i have install it works! the path was Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "C:/ImageMagick/SourceCode"